# 2 default gateway to one subnet. One gateway in security device and other one in 2960 XR switch

Tags: cisco

Subnet 10.3.20.0/26 connected to switch (multilayer) through a vlan. Same vlan there is no svi in that switch. This vlan extended to Asa one interface and gave one ip address and that IP address is using as default gateway to above subnet. One new scenario has come now, one server to be connected to this subnet and it will not connect to asa, so we have to create svi in switch and provide this IP address as default gateway for the new server. My question if I am using that whether any problem occurs in existing setup because here two gateway coming in one subnet. Hope you understood my point, can any one help in this case.

Comment: Is the server meant to have internet access? Or is the SVI meant only to allow intervlan traffic between the server and the other VLANs?

Comment: As far as having multiple gateways is concerned, there shouldn't be any problem. No other device will know about the SVI unless you configure them to use the SVI as their gateway.  All of your other network devices will be unaffected by the SVI.

Comment: THANKS for the reply. That means two gateway for one subnet will not cause problem unless one server is using multiple gateway (different Ethernet card) for traffic..